# Upload image using xcode (MySQL + PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, ios, iphone, xcode

I'm trying to upload an image to a MySQL database using PHP in XCODE but I'm having some problems because it's not working. It's working fine when the user inserts a text, but when it comes to an image I can't make it.

I have read some tutorials and example but they are not working in my xcode project. Can you help me with this problem?

That's my code:

```
- (IBAction)uploadPhoto:(UIButton *)sender {

    NSLog(@"Photo enviada");
    /*
    NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://example.com/upload.php?image=%@",_imageView.image];
    NSData *dataURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];
    NSString *strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@", strResult);
    */
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(_imageView.image, 90);
    NSString *urlString = @"http://autograpp.com/upload.php";

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"];
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"ipodfile.jpg\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [request setHTTPBody:body];

    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```

But I'm getting an error on:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
```

**ARC forbids explicit message send of autorelease.**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the datatype of the respective image field?

Comment: Hello. How can I see the datatype of the image? Thanks again for your help ursitesion.

Comment: As per my understanding, you have to insert image into a column of a table. When you create a table, you have to define the datatype of columns. In the column in which you have to store the image, please choose the datatype as `blob`. 
To know more about `blob` datatype, please refer `http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html`

Comment: Thanks ursitesion. I just only have a UIImageView and that's what I want to save in my FTP and in my database. How can I do that? because it's working with some text, but it isn't with the image. Thanks again.

Comment: Have you any idea about database?

Comment: Yes, I know PHP and MySQL. I just need the process in the xcode project. Thanks again ursitesion.

Comment: I have no idea about using database operation in xcode. I thought I could help in mysql perspective. Thats why I was trying to clarify the question...

Answer (score 0):

You are using `- autorelease` in an ARC-enabled project; this is neither necessary nor allowed. This code is probably a bit older and pre-dates ARC (automatic reference counting.)

If you replace

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
```

with

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
```

it should work.

In ARC, you do not have to retain/release objects any more; this is done automatically.